# Inconsistent advanced indexing in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Why are the following indexing forms produce differently shaped outputs?

```
a = np.zeros((5, 5, 5, 5))
print(a[:, :, [1, 2], [3, 4]].shape)
# (5, 5, 2)

print(a[:, :, 1:3, [3, 4]].shape)
#(5, 5, 2, 2)
```

Almost certain I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: This is how advanced indexing works with __broadcasting__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one,

```
a[:, :, [1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

takes indices pairwise and selects the following subarrays:

```
a[:, :, 1, 3]
a[:, :, 2, 4]
```

whereas the second one generates all possible combos (and shapes it accordingly), i.e.

```
a[:, :, 1, 3]
a[:, :, 1, 4]
a[:, :, 2, 3]
a[:, :, 2, 4]
```

This can be verified by running the following exercise. Rather than initializing `a` as a zero array, use `np.arange` and reshape it

```
a = np.arange(5**4).reshape((5, 5, 5, 5))
print(a[:, :, [1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

The first few lines of the output are

```
[[[  8  14]
  [ 33  39]
  [ 58  64]...
```

and the array `a` itself is

```
[[[[  0   1   2   3   4]
   [  5   6   7   8   9]
   [ 10  11  12  13  14]
   [ 15  16  17  18  19]
   [ 20  21  22  23  24]]...
```

So 8 comes at (1,3) (In the innermost 2D array, 1: 2nd row, 3:4th column) as expected and 14 comes at (2, 4). Similarly, 33 is also at index (1,3) and 39 at (2,4) in the next 2D subarray.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, but [`list` doesn't work that way](http://ideone.com/76OhYD).

Comment: @user2357112 I think numpy arrays do. Why would the exercise give that result then?

Comment: No, I mean the expressions like `list(a[:, :, 1, 3], a[:, :, 2, 4])` and `list(a[:, :, 1, 3], a[:, :, 2, 3], a[:, :, 2, 3], a[:, :, 2, 4])` that you've given don't make any sense.

Comment: If you meant the ordering, my bad. I was just trying to highlight that using indexing would select all possible combinations but defining explicit lists might make it generates pairs. Incorporating the changes. Thanks for highlighting.

Answer (score 5):

`[1, 2], [3, 4]` doesn't mean "select indices 1 and 2 in one dimension and 3 and 4 in another". It means "select the *pairs* of indices (1, 3) and (2, 4)".

Your first expression select all elements at locations of the form `a, b, c, d` where `a` and `b` can be any index and `c` and `d` must be either the pair `(1, 3)` or the pair `(2, 4)`.

Your second expression selects all elements at locations of the form `a, b, c, d` where `a` and `b` can be any index, `c` must be in the half-open range [1, 3), and `d` must be either 3 or 4. Unlike the first one, c and d are allowed to be `(2, 3)` or `(1, 4)`.

---

Note that using both basic and advanced indexing in the same indexing expression (which mostly means mixing `:` and advanced indexing) has [unintuitive effects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing) on the order of the axes of the result. It's best to avoid mixing them.

Comment: It's a little more subtle than `pairwise`; The lists are 'broadcast' against each other.  In this case (2,),(2,)->(2,).  If one is a 'column vector' we get a block: `a[:, :, [[1], [2],[3]], [3, 4]]` produces a (5,5,3,2) array,

Comment: @hpaulj: Yeah, in its full generality, it's a lot more complex than what this answer describes. Since the broadcasting is a NOP in this example, I didn't mention it.

Comment: @hpaulj: In this case broadcasting (3,1),(2,) -> (3,1),(1,2) -> (3,2), right?

Comment: @Rainning, right, the first step of broadcasting is to add leading size 1 dimensions as needed. Here (2,) to (1,2)

Answer (score 0):

When you have several lists in advanced indexing, it indicates that those should be taken pairwise. By comparision, when you use slices, you get each in the lists for all in the slice.

To see the difference, consider:

```
>>> print(a[:, :, [1, 2, 3], [3, 4]].shape)
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)
```

This is since the first list has length 3, and the second length 2. These do not match, and you get an error.

By comparison, if you use a slice it works perfectly:

```
>>> print(a[:, :, 1:4, [3, 4]].shape)
(5, 5, 3, 2)
```

#### Explanation

To see why this is the case, we consult [the numpy indexing documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing), which states:

> When the index consists of as many integer arrays as the array being indexed has dimensions, the indexing is straight forward, but different from slicing.
>
> Advanced indexes always are broadcast and iterated as one:
>
> ```
> result[i_1, ..., i_M] == x[ind_1[i_1, ..., i_M], ind_2[i_1, ..., i_M],
>                        ..., ind_N[i_1, ..., i_M]]
> ```

Comment: Marked as solution another answer, because it wasn't clear from your answer what means "taken pairwise". Thanks anyway! It's crazy how it took only couple minutes to have three answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case: Both `[1,2]` and `[3,4]` are of shape `(2,)`, which **together** result in a **single** (array-)dimension of shape `(2,)`. So in the first result, you got `(5,5,2)`, where the last `(2,)` is newly created during the process.

On the second case: the only list `[3,4]` **itself** results in one (array-)dimension of shape `(2,)`. And the slicing `1:3` only changes the length of its own (array-)dimension into `2`. Thus the result `(5,5,2,2)`.